# How to check if the ID of a movie in my App exist in my DB or not

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mvvm, dao

I am using Room + View Model

i want to check if the ID for the movie exist in the DB or not , in order to know if the user added it to the favourite or not to change the button colour and text and to remove it from DB if the button clicked again.

I don't know how to implement if statement to implement it , i tried a lot  of things but it doesn't work.

***this is My MovieDetailActivity***

```
public class MovieActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayout;

    public Context context;

    // Constant for default task id to be used when not in favourite
    private static final int DEFAULT_TASK_ID = -1;

    ToggleButton button;
    AppDatabase appDatabase;
    Movie movie;
    int id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.movies_details);

        appDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        movie = intent.getParcelableExtra("get_data");

        id = movie.getId();


        checkFavorite();

        if (id != DEFAULT_TASK_ID) {
            AddTaskViewModelFactory factory = new AddTaskViewModelFactory(appDatabase, id);
            final AddTaskViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(AddTaskViewModel.class);
            viewModel.getTask().observe(this, new Observer<Movie>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(Movie movie) {
                    viewModel.getTask().removeObserver(this);
                    button.setTextOn("Added");
                    button.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen);
                }
            });
        }

        button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (b) {
                    compoundButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(compoundButton.getContext(), R.color.colorGreen));
                    addToFavourite();
                } else {
                    compoundButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(compoundButton.getContext(), R.color.colorGrey));
                    deleteFromFavourite();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void addToFavourite() {
        AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(() -> {
            appDatabase.movieDao().insert(movie);
            Log.d("the movie ID added  " + id, "   good");
        });
    }

    public void deleteFromFavourite() {
        AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(() -> {
            appDatabase.movieDao().delete(movie);
            Log.d("the movie ID deleted  " + id, "   bad");

        });
    }

    public void checkFavorite() {
        AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(() -> {

            appDatabase.movieDao().getAllMovies(id);

            if (appDatabase.movieDao().check(id) != 0) {
                button.setTextOn("Added");
                button.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen);
            }
            Log.d("the movie ID deleted  " + id, "   bad");
        });
    }

}
```

***this is my Dao***

```
@Dao
public interface MovieDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Movies_Table WHERE id = :id")
    LiveData<Movie> getAllMovies(int id);

    @Update()
    void update(Movie m);

    @Query("SELECT id FROM Movies_Table WHERE id = :id")
    int check(int id);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(Movie m);

    @Delete()
    void delete(Movie m);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Movies_Table ")
    LiveData<List<Movie>> getAllMovies();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the DAOs `check` method:

```java
    @Query("SELECT count(id) FROM Movies_Table WHERE id = :id")
    int check(int id);
```

and it will return 0 if the movie with id doesn't exists and non-zero if it exists in the table

Comment: but if i already have a movie in my DB and checking for another one then it will also return non zero , Am i right ??